# list1.erase( hash1.find ( p) ); no matching function to call 'erase' c++

Tags: c++, list, c++11, unordered-map

Why doesn't it accept hash1.find(p) but hash1[p] works find if i use that?

```
class LRUCACHE {
    list<int> list1;   // store keys of Cache.

    unordered_map<int, list<int>::const_iterator> hash1;     // Store reference of Keys in Cache.
    int maxsize;

public:
    LRUCACHE(int);
    void set(int);
    void get(int);
};

LRUCACHE::LRUCACHE(int n) {    
    maxsize = n;
}


void LRUCACHE::get(int x) {
    // Not Found in Cache.
    if (hash1.find(x) == hash1.end() ) {

        // if Max size.
        if (list1.size() == maxsize ) {

            // returns the last element of LIST.
            int last = list1.back();

            // Remove last element of LIST and reduce size by 1.
            list1.pop_back();

            hash1.erase(last); 
        }
    }
    else {
        list1.erase(hash1[x]);
    }
    list1.push_front(x);
    hash1[x] = list1.begin(); // points and updates.
}

void LRUCACHE::get(int p) {
    if (hash1.find(p) == hash1.end() ){
        cout << "not found " << endl;
    }
    else {
        list1.erase(hash1.find(p)); // Error Here member function not found
    }
}
```

I think im using const_iterator for unordermap? so it should accept it list function call of iterator erase( const_iterator position ); ?

i think hash1.find should return const_iterator?

Comment: `hash1[p]` will create a key-value pair for the key `p` if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::unordered_map::find()` returns an iterator, not the value in the map. So what you get is `std::unordered_map<int, std::list<int>::const_iterator>>::iterator` (or `std::unordered_map<int, std::list<int>::const_iterator>>::const_iterator`)

You can retrieve the value in map under iterator by using `hash1.find(x)->second`:

```
void LRUCACHE::get(int p) {
    const auto iter = hash1.find(p);
    if (iter == hash1.end() ){
        cout << "not found " << endl;
    } else {
        list1.erase(iter->second); 
    }
}
```

`std::unordered_map::operator[]` on the other hand doesn't return an iterator, but a reference to the value in map under the key. Which means no further extraction is needed to directly access the value.

Comment: ohhh i thought std::unordered_map::find() can return const_iterator
      iterator find ( const key_type& k );
const_iterator find ( const key_type& k ) const;

Comment: @Kenny It can. But it is iterator to `std::unordered_map`, not iterator to `std::list` which you store in your map